# ms-access string in SQL vba

Tags: ms-access

after trying '" text "' or (" text ") and some other combination after reading similar issue on RunSQL without success, hence i have to seek the more opinion here:

using Design Query and able to provide the correct SQL statement below:

```
INSERT INTO db_Doc_Child_SX ( Child_Doc_DD, Parent_Doc, Child_Doc, Doc_Detail_Rec )
SELECT Date() AS Expr1, db_Doc_D_bl.Doc_Rec, [Doc_Rec] & "-" & DatePart("d",Date()) AS Expr2, db_Doc_D_bl.Doc_Detail_Rec
FROM db_Doc_D_bl
WHERE (((db_Doc_D_bl.Doc_Detail_Rec)=[Forms]![Fm_Doc_Child_SX]![db_Doc_D_bl subform].[Form]![Doc_Detail_Rec]) AND ((db_Doc_D_bl.SX_Sent)=True));
```

the error code is - Compile Error: Expected: end of statement and highlight the d between the "".

In the Past encountering such issue, i always think of other alternative to overcome it without actually facing this issue and now i think i wish to learn properly and face this string / text with "" in the SQL statement under vba and hope senior who has the deep experience can share the proper syntax for this SQL statement.

many thanks and regards.

edit: Mr. @deluxeinformation got the right syntax and got the SQL statement to pass it without error! so the right syntax is

```
INSERT INTO db_Doc_Child_SX ( Child_Doc_DD, Parent_Doc, Child_Doc, Doc_Detail_Rec )
SELECT Date() AS Expr1, db_Doc_D_bl.Doc_Rec, [Doc_Rec] & '-' & DatePart('d',Date()) AS Expr2, db_Doc_D_bl.Doc_Detail_Rec
FROM db_Doc_D_bl
WHERE (((db_Doc_D_bl.Doc_Detail_Rec)=[Forms]![Fm_Doc_Child_SX]![db_Doc_D_bl subform].[Form]![Doc_Detail_Rec]) AND ((db_Doc_D_bl.SX_Sent)=True));
```

Comment: as temp solution (as always trying while waiting for proper method to do it) i created a textbox and use vba to store the datepart("d",Date()) (or Day(date()) as per senior Gustav) and edit the sql statement AppendSQL = AppendSQL & "SELECT Date() AS Expr1, db_Doc_D_bl.Doc_Rec, [Doc_Rec] & " & " - " & "[Forms]![Fm_Doc_Child_SX]![txtDate] AS Expr2, db_Doc_D_bl.Doc_Detail_Rec " and without issue and succeed append to the db as intended... still waiting for more possible solution...

Comment: Always avoid double quotes inside SQL statements for any literals even if the dialect supports interchanging with single quotes. In the SQL standard, double quotes are used as symbols for identifiers (but not in Access SQL) and so are not equivalent to single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Try with single-quotes:

```
 [Doc_Rec] & "-" & DatePart('d',Date()) AS Expr2
```

or use *Day*:

```
 [Doc_Rec] & "-" & CStr(Day(Date())) AS Expr2
```

Comment: day(date()) i though should have but i cant seem to google it when i tried month() and year(). Tested SELECT Date() AS Expr1, db_Doc_D_bl.Doc_Rec, [Doc_Rec] & "-" & Day(Date()) AS Expr2, db_Doc_D_bl.Doc_Detail_Rec and the vba error is 'type mismatch'. The field that store the data is already in Short Text. Could it be "-" since is also " which caused the statement 'close' prematurely?

Comment: Try adding `CStr`. It shouldn't be needed. If still error, it must be something else.

Comment: Yes, you will need to exchange double quotes (") with single quotes on "-" as well so your SQL string would become 
"INSERT INTO db_Doc_Child_SX (Child_Doc_DD,Parent_Doc,Child_Doc,Doc_Detail_Rec) SELECT DATE() AS Expr1, db_Doc_D_bl.Doc_Rec,[Doc_Rec] & '-' & DATEPART('d',DATE()) AS Expr2, db_Doc_D_bl.Doc_Detail_Rec FROM db_Doc_D_bl WHERE db_Doc_D_bl.Doc_Detail_Rec=[Forms]![Fm_Doc_Child_SX]![db_Doc_D_bl subform].[Form]![Doc_Detail_Rec] AND db_Doc_D_bl.SX_Sent=True"

Comment: @Gustav cstr([Doc_Rec] & " - " & Day(Date())) AS Expr2 stll produce the type mismatch error.

Comment: and holly molly! @deluxeinformation suggestion got it without error! darn and why i didnt think so that!! at least now i could go back to all those SQL Statement which has similar issue with " and apply this new knowledge! Many thanks to those who read and responded!